# Unable To read file present on H2O Cluster in RStudio

Tags: r, h2o

I am connected to H2O Cluster and was trying to read the .csv file in R but not able to read it.

Giving below command after connecting to Cluster:

data = h2o.importFile(path = "/tmp", pattern = ".*.csv", destination_frame = "train-0.01m")

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using importFolder as below when passing a path with pattern:

> data = h2o.importFolder(path = "/Users/avkashchauhan/learn/datasets", pattern = ".*.csv", destination_frame = "trainx")
>
> |================================================| 100%

Comment: To clarify -- `h2o.importFile()` doesn't have a `pattern` argument, only `h2o.importFolder()` does.